# Which one to use skipPolicy or ItemListenerSupport?

Tags: spring

I want to write an error csv file whenever a DB insertion failed due to data error or a invalid row comes in csv file even before the db call. On error, I need to skip the record as well.

I come across below 2 options

1. A class which implements `SkipPolicy` - write csv file here and skip the record (or)
2. Use `ItemListenerSupport` to write csv on error

Clarification

1. which one to use and best practice to go?
2. will the `ItemListenerSupport` continues processing the file after the error record or just stops as soon as it has error record. say have 5,000 records and an error record exist in 1050, 4032, 4578 etc.,

Thanks

Comment: Those are 2 differnt things (so read again). The `SkipPolicy` is to decide if a row should be skipped and processing to continue or the whole job should be stopped. This is not meant to be used to write something to a file for that you need a listener (either `ItemListenerSupport` or one of the `@OnSkipIn*` annotations). So you will need both, not either.

Comment: @M.Deinum So you mean skipPolicy - we can decide whether row can be skipped. Assume due to an error, i am skipping an error. The same errored row will come on ItemListenerSupport so that i can write the csv file. Is my understanding is correct? One is to skip or not (public class MySkipPolicy implements SkipPolicy) and another one (class MySkipListener extends SkipListenerSupport) is what we should do on skip....So we need both...Is that right?

Comment: Yes you do. Do you need both, not necessarily as there are already default `SkipPolicy` implementations available which can be configured.

Comment: @M.Deinum That's the reason asking which one is the best practice to choose as both should not be used. skip or listener. Basically want to write errors of invalid rows or db errorrs or reasons as new csv file for errored record. Please let me know your suggestion.

Comment: Again you need both, but that doesn't mean you need to implement both yourself. There are plenty of `SkipPolicy` instances (with easy configuration) available which probably suit your needs (what those needs are I don't know). What to do with your rows is specific to your usecase and thus you will need a custom item listener.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry to bother again. I understand now..We need both but for skip we can use existing skip policies. Can you please help me with 1 or two links for both of them ? That should be really helpful. Since you are an expert in this, it would be greatly appreciated if you can share or reliable one to go through

Comment: @M.Deinum Now i am facing issue with simpleStepBuilder.writer(writer).listener(new MyFileItemListener()); -> where MyFileItemListener extends ItemListenerSupport...However builder says The method listener(Object) is ambiguous for the type SimpleStepBuilder. Please let me know how to resolve this error